# Dropping a connected user from an Oracle 10g database schema

Tags: oracle

Is there a better way to forcefully disconnect all users from an Oracle 10g database schema than restarting the Oracle database services?

We have several developers using SQL Developer connecting to the same schema on a single Oracle 10g server.  The problem is that when we want to drop the schema to rebuild it, inevitably someone is still connected and we cannot drop the database schema or the user while someone is still connected.

By the same token, we do not want to drop all connections to other schemas because other people may still be connected and testing with those schemas.

Anyone know of a quick way to resolve this?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

To find the sessions, as a DBA use

> `select sid,serial# from v$session where username = '<your_schema>'`

If you want to be sure only to get the sessions that use SQL Developer, you can add `and program = 'SQL Developer'`. If you only want to kill sessions belonging to a specific developer, you can add a restriction on `os_user`

Then kill them with

> `alter system kill session '<sid>,<serial#>'`
>
> (e.g. `alter system kill session '39,1232'`)

A query that produces ready-built kill-statements could be

> `select 'alter system kill session ''' || sid || ',' || serial# || ''';' from v$session where username = '<your_schema>'`

This will return one kill statement per session for that user - something like:

`alter system kill session '375,64855';`

`alter system kill session '346,53146';`

Comment: I found that in our RAC environment, killing the session often left it hanging, but finding out the process id and killing it from the operating system always worked.

Comment: small addition - add immediate to the command : `select 'alter system kill session ''' || sid || ',' || serial# || ''' immediate;' from v$session where username = '<your_schema>';` this will force the command

Comment: And probably obvious but username ('<your_schema>' above) should be in uppercase

Answer (score 19):

Find existing sessions to DB using this query:

```
SELECT s.inst_id,
       s.sid,
       s.serial#,
       p.spid,
       s.username,
       s.program
FROM   gv$session s
       JOIN gv$process p ON p.addr = s.paddr AND p.inst_id = s.inst_id
WHERE  s.type != 'BACKGROUND';
```

you'll see something like below.
[image: Oracle Sessions]

Then, run below query with values extracted from above results.

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '<put above s.sid here>,<put above s.serial# here>';
```

Ex:
*ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '93,943';*

Answer (score 9):

my proposal is this simple anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
   lc_username   VARCHAR2 (32) := 'user-name-to-kill-here';
BEGIN
   FOR ln_cur IN (SELECT sid, serial# FROM v$session WHERE username = lc_username)
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ''' || ln_cur.sid || ',' || ln_cur.serial# || ''' IMMEDIATE');
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: better to note ospid  before killing sessions, they may got stuck

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you alter the system and enable restricted session before you kill them or they will quickly log back into the database before you get your work completed.

Comment: Might be easier, and less intrusive, to lock the user he intends to drop, then kill off all connected sessions on that user, then drop it and re-create.  No need to unnecessarily restrict access to other users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION?  Get the SID and SERIAL# from V$SESSION for each session in the given schema, then do

ALTER SCHEMA KILL SESSION *sid*,*serial#*;

Answer (score 0):

just use SQL :

```
disconnect; 

conn tiger/scott as sysdba;
```