# Dropping connected users in Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I want to drop some users in Oracle DB using sqlplus but I am getting error:

```
SQL> DROP USER test CASCADE;
DROP USER test CASCADE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected
```

I followed the link in SO to find out the sessions - [Dropping a connected user from an Oracle 10g database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85804/dropping-a-connected-user-from-an-oracle-10g-database-schema)

But when I ran the command I am not getting any results:

```
SQL> select sid,serial# from v$session where username = 'test';

no rows selected
```

Please help me how to drop users in this case.

Comment: You answer may be here: http://anilanbu.blogspot.com/2012/02/ora-01940-cannot-drop-user-that-is.html

Comment: I tried that but I am not getting any rows when I tried to find out the sessions.

Comment: I found out why I am not getting session records, my where condition should be on username='TEST'

Comment: @user2065083-If you still get ORA-01940:... then check the query again.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Users are all capitals in `v$session` (and data dictionary views). If you match  with capitals you should find your session to kill.

```
SELECT s.sid, s.serial#, s.status, p.spid 
  FROM v$session s, v$process p 
 WHERE s.username = 'TEST' --<<<--
  AND p.addr(+) = s.paddr
 /
```

Pass actual SID and SERIAL# values for user TEST then drop user...:

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '<SID>, <SERIAL>'
/
```

Comment: @SkylarSaveland `select 'alter system kill session ''' || sid || ',' || serial# || ''';' from v$session where username = '<your_schema>'` will do it for you.

Comment: As described below, maybe you need to execute `alter system kill ... immediate;`

Comment: This solves the issue only if there is a row in v$session.  If there isn't - which occurred for me when a previous drop command failed half way through - then only the shutdown/restart as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21700385/1081849 worked for me.

Answer (score 46):

Solution :

login as sysdaba:

```
sqlplus  / as sysdba
```

then:

```
sql>Shutdown immediate;

sql>startup restrict;

sql>drop user TEST cascade;
```

If you want to re-activate DB normally either reset the server or :

```
sql>Shutdown immediate;

sql>startup;
```

:)

Comment: The actual best solution.

Comment: You can also revert the RESTRICT option by using the following:
ALTER SYSTEM DISABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;

Comment: Please, rebooting the server to drop an account is far from the best solution. Think about a Production environment. 
This is a pretty bad idea. To prevent the user from reconnecting when you kill the session, you can LOCK the account first, then kill any sessions with that username and then drop the account. 
No need to reboot a server for that.

Comment: If you connect to a pluggable database, SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE can lock you out. In my case, I immediately got an "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor" and got disconnected. Luckily another account on the machine had set up its environment correctly to connect and restart.

Comment: The OP had searched for user using wrong case hence no rows found.  However in my case a previous drop user command had failed half way through, leaving my db in state where i could no longer drop user and user but could not find row in v$session.  Only this answer solved it for me.

Comment: @sbk I have the same issue but didn't realize what caused it. I was getting error `ORA-01940` but didn't display in `v$session` or `v$process`.

Answer (score 8):

Issue has been fixed using below procedure :

```
DECLARE
  v_user_exists NUMBER;
  user_name CONSTANT varchar2(20) := 'SCOTT';
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FOR c IN (SELECT s.sid, s.serial# FROM v$session s WHERE upper(s.username) = user_name)
    LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'alter system kill session ''' || c.sid || ',' || c.serial# || ''' IMMEDIATE';
    END LOOP;
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop user ' || user_name || ' cascade';
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF (SQLCODE = -1940) THEN
        NULL;
      ELSE
        RAISE;
      END IF;
    END;
    BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_user_exists FROM dba_users WHERE username = user_name;
      EXIT WHEN v_user_exists = 0;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 5):

Do a query:

`SELECT * FROM v$session s;`

Find your user and do the next query (with appropriate parameters):

`ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '<SID>, <SERIAL>';`

Answer (score 3):

If you use RAC then you need to use `GV$*` views instead `V$*`.
Try to find your session by

```
select * from gv$session where username = 'test';
```

and then you can kill the session by

```
alter system kill session 'sid, serial#, @inst_id' immediate;
```

Answer (score 1):

go to services in administrative tools and select oracleserviceSID and restart it

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to follow the flow described here - but haven't luck to completely kill the session.. Then I fond additional step here:
http://wyding.blogspot.com/2013/08/solution-for-ora-01940-cannot-drop-user.html

What I did:
 1. `select 'alter system kill session ''' || sid || ',' || serial# || ''';' from v$session where username = '<your_schema>';` - as described below.
Out put will be something like this:
`alter system kill session '22,15' immediate;`
 2. `alter system disconnect session '22,15' IMMEDIATE ;` - 22-sid, 15-serial - repeat the command for each returned session from previous command
 
    3. Repeat steps 1-2 while `select...` not return an empty table
 
    4. Call
    `drop user...`

What was missed - call `alter system disconnect session '22,15' IMMEDIATE ;` for each of session returned by `select 'alter system kill session '..`

Comment: You should add comment to first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes [Oracle drop user](https://orahow.com/how-to-drop-user-in-oracle/) takes long time to execute. In that case user might be connected to the database. Better you can kill user session and drop the user.

`SQL> select 'alter system kill session ''' || sid || ',' || serial# || ''' immediate;' from v$session where username ='&USERNAME';`

`SQL> DROP USER barbie CASCADE;`

Answer (score 1):

This can be as simple as:

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;

SQL> DROP USER test CASCADE;

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM DISABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I believe that killing all sessions should be the solution, but...

I found similar discussion - https://community.oracle.com/thread/1054062 to my problem and that was I had no sessions for that users, but I still received the error. I tried also second the best answer:

```
sql>Shutdown immediate;

sql>startup restrict;

sql>drop user TEST cascade;
```

What worked for me at the end was to login as the user, drop all tables manually - select for creating drop statements is

```
select 'drop table ' || TABLE_NAME || ';'  from user_tables;
```

(Needs to be re-run several times because of references)

I have no idea how is that related, I dropped also functions and sequences (because that was all I had in schema)

When I did that and I logged off, I had several sessions in `v$session` table and when I killed those I was able to drop user.

My DB was still started in restricted mode (not sure if important or not).

Might help someone else.

BTW: my Oracle version is `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
SELECT sid || ',' || serial# AS process FROM v$session WHERE username = UPPER('<YOUR_USERNAME>')
```

It will return the list of processes; e.g.,

- 48,42125
- 50,19799
- 51,32250

Second,

```
alter system kill session '<process(the sid,serial#)>';
```

In my case, deleting the **immediate** from the second query helped.

Comment: Please consider formatting your answer differently, so the code can be read and understood more easily.

Comment: @KorbenDose is right, of course. I’ve taken the liberty of editing your answer in an attempt to clarify it, but you should review my [edit] to make sure it’s consistent with your expectations.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, Oracle config in default affects letter register. In exact my Scheme_Name was written all Capital letters. You can see your Scheme_Name on "Other Users" tab, if you are using Oracle S

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I "automate" Dropping connected users in Oracle database:

```
# A shell script to Drop a Database Schema, forcing off any Connected Sessions (for example, before an Import) 
# Warning! With great power comes great responsibility.
# It is often advisable to take an Export before Dropping a Schema

if [ "$1" = "" ] 
then
    echo "Which Schema?"
    read schema
else
    echo "Are you sure? (y/n)"
    read reply
    [ ! $reply = y ] && return 1
    schema=$1
fi

sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF
set echo on
alter user $schema account lock;
-- Exterminate all sessions!
begin     
  for x in ( select sid, serial# from v\$session where username=upper('$schema') )
  loop  
   execute immediate ( 'alter system kill session '''|| x.Sid || ',' || x.Serial# || ''' immediate' );  
  end loop;  
  dbms_lock.sleep( seconds => 2 ); -- Prevent ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected
end;
/
drop user $schema cascade;
quit
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//'SYS' is username from where you wanted to kill session'
SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE = 'SYS';

**Step 1:**

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sys.kill_session(p_sid NUMBER, p_serial NUMBER)
AS
v_user VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(username)
INTO v_user
FROM v$session
WHERE sid = p_sid
AND serial# = p_serial;
**Step 2**
create or replace procedure kill_session( p_sid in number, p_serial# in number)
 is v_count pls_integer;
 BEGIN
 select count(*) into v_count
 from V$session
 where username = 'SYS'
 and sid = p_sid
 and serial# = p_serial# ;
 if ( v_count = 1 )
 then
 execute immediate '
 alter system kill session ''' ||
 to_char(p_sid,'999999')||','||
 to_char(p_serial#,'999999')||'''';
 else
 raise_application_error( -20001,
 'You do not own session ''' ||
 p_sid || ',' || p_serial# ||
 '''' );
end if;
 END;
 /
 
**Step 3**
 grant execute on kill_session to SYS;
**Step 4**
select inst_id, sid, serial#, username, action, program, service_name, con_id from gv$session where username like 'FCM_469';
Check there will be no sessions now
**Step 5**
DROP USER USER_345 CASCADE;
Output:User Dropped
```