# Oracle: automate dropping and recreating connected user

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to DROP a connected user with Oracle. This question has been asked well over 700 million times, thanks to Oracle being a great software product. All answers I find, however, require user input and can not be automated as posted. The typical answer is well stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15665694/177293

I want to do this in a script without a human having to intervene. So, I'm trying like this:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT sid, serial# from v$session where username = 'MYUSER'
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || i.sid || ',' || i.serial# || ''';';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Which, hilariously, in sqlplus results in:

```
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Trying a slightly different tactic:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT
        'alter system kill session ''' || sid || ',' || serial# || ''';'
        from v$session where username = 'MYUSER'
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''|| i ||'';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

results in:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''|| i ||'';
                      *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 21:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 7, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I'm hoping to have a finished script that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

sqlplus system/manager <<EOT
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT sid, serial# FROM v$session WHERE username = 'MYUSER'
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || i.sid || ',' || i.serial# || ''';';
    END LOOP;
END;
DROP USER MYUSER CASCADE;
DROP TABLESPACE MYUSER INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
CREATE USER MYUSER IDENTIFIED BY password;
ALTER USER MYUSER IDENTIFIED BY password;
GRANT connect, resource TO MYUSER;
exit;
EOT
```

What is wrong with the above?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with the above scripts is that `;` should not be in dynamic SQL.

But don't let that fool you, this is still an incredibly difficult problem.  Unfortunately, it is rare for Oracle systems to frequently drop and re-create users.  This means you will run into lots of weird bugs.

I've built scripts to do this, but unfortunately cannot share them here.  Here are some of the fun things you have to look forward to:

1. Killing connected sessions.
2. Killing other sessions that are blocking objects owned by your session.
3. Truncating temporary tables because they have weird locking rules.  And killing sessions using them, see HOW TO DIAGNOSE AN ORA-14452 DURING DROP OF TEMPORARY TABLE (Doc ID 800506.1).
4. Using INST_ID in the KILL syntax, for RAC.
5. Looping through the whole process a few times, in case an application is spawning new sessions that lock objects.
6. If you're using object-relational code, execute `dbms_session.reset_package`.  Amazingly, some objects can persist even after dropping and recreating their owners.

Expect to write about a hundred lines of code, if it's a complicated application.  Expect to spend a few weeks of testing to shake out some weird bugs.  Expect it to still fail occasionally.

Yes, this is ridiculous.  Oracle spends a lot of effort on ways to quickly create new databases; transportable tablespaces, pluggable databases, virtualization, etc.  You'd think there would be a good way to reliably drop and recreate a user!

Comment: I don't really understand why you think it should be easy to drop an active user in an active system whose objects may actually be in use by applications at the time.  Seems like a thing that ought to be hard.

Comment: Since your intent is to drop the whole schema anyway, perhaps first revoking all the grants on the user's objects would be helpful.  Then you couldn't have new sessions in other accounts locking those objects.

Comment: @DaveCosta I see your point, it's usually gonna be difficult to drop or delete something that's being used.  But part of the problem is that Oracle has a fuzzy definition of what's "active", specifically for temporary tables.  It's really annoying the way a session can block things even when it doesn't have any active transactions.