# How to kill running sessions of a user in oracle with single sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to automate following scenario -

`Kill all of sessions of a user.`

I want to achieve this in single sql query. I looked at [Dropping connected users in Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664924/dropping-connected-users-in-oracle-database/15665694#15665694) and one of the comments has given single sql query, but that is not helping kill all sessions in single query.

Can someone help me with single query to kill all session of a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put (as far as I can tell), you can't do that.

Sessions are killed one-by-one, not *all-sessions-for-user*.

If you want to do that using a single line of code (as a final result), create a stored procedure which will do the job for you.

Connected as user which has privileges to do that (such as SYS, unless you created your own user for such purposes):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> create or replace procedure p_kill (par_username in varchar2) is
  2    l_str varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select s.sid, s.serial#
  5                  from v$session s
  6                  where s.username = par_username
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      l_str := 'alter system kill session ' || chr(39) ||
 10                cur_r.sid || ', '|| cur_r.serial# || chr(39);
 11      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 12      execute immediate l_str;
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.
```

I have two sessions (opened in two separate SQL*Plus windows) for user MIKE and I want to kill them all:

```
SQL> exec p_kill ('MIKE');
alter system kill session '12, 133'
alter system kill session '139, 265'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

How does it reflect to MIKE? Like this:

```
SQL> select * From tab;
select * From tab
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00028: your session has been killed


SQL>
```

So, as you can see, at the end this is all you need:

```
exec p_kill ('MIKE');
```