# Oracle 9i database - ORA-00054 RESOURCE BUSY

Tags: oracle9i, rowlocking

Looking for some advice. Yesterday, a colleague tried to update a row in an Oracle 9i database via Toad. She killed Toad in Task Manager as it hung as Not Responding. Now, when we try to update the row, we get the ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified. We access the database with a VPN connection which has since been disconnected. I'm not a DBA but I thought that oracle would clean up any old sessions/locks after some time?
Is there any way to fix this or should I contact a DBA to have a look?

Comment: Usually, but it depends. The fact it appeared to hang might mean it was updating much more than expected, or maybe there was a trigger or some other side effect that caused a problem. You might just have a really high session timeout. If you can identify the session you can kill it; or rather, your DBA can. It should then roll back any updates and locks it's holding. (Your DBA should know how to do that, and you shouldn't be able to if you aren't the DBA, so there's probably not much point adding an answer to [show how it's done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/86739/266304)...)

Comment: Thanks for that Alex, very helpful. Will contact the DBA to look into this as I do not have administrative rights for the database. Thanks again.